# Using an 'If' statement to check JSON data webhook response

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, webhooks

I am using the requests library and made a request to the twitch api. I have filtered the data into variables but I would like to know if there was a way I could use an 'If' statement on the variables. The data is stored as JSON.

Edit: I don't get any errors but the code just doesn't run.

My code is below:

```
client = discord.Client()
token = open("token.txt", "r").read()
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb url")
mydb = myclient["Cluster0"]
mycol = mydb["live"]

cursor = mycol.find({ "type": "user" }, {'_id': 0, 'twitch': 1, 'channelID': 1})
for item in cursor:
    x = item.get('twitch')
    channelid = item.get('channelID')
    print(x)
    print(channelid)

headers = {
    'client-id': 'twitch client id',
    'Authorization': 'twitch ouath token',
}

params = (
    ('query', x),
)

response = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/search/channels', headers=headers, params=params)

final = response.json()

finali = final['data'][0]['is_live']

finale = final['data'][0]['thumbnail_url']

finaly = final['data'][0]['title']

finalo = final['data'][0]['started_at']

print(final)

# I would like the If here, Eg. If finali == "True":
async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    print("someone live")
    channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
    while not client.is_closed():
        counter += 1
        embedVar2 = discord.Embed(title="" + x + " is now live on Twitch!", description="" + finaly + "", url="https://twitch.tv/" + x + "", color=0x0C8BC2)
        embedVar2.set_image(url="" + finale + "")
        await channel.send("@everyone")
        await channel.send(embed=embedVar2)
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('token')
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
more details or clarify of problem, include the current result, include the expected result.
See [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finali should return a bool from that json so rather than testing `if finali == "True"` you'd just check: `if finali:` which is `if finali == True` but shorter.

So the answer is yes you can use an if statement with those variables.

Comment: Hi, I get an invalid syntax with ```If finali:```

Comment: it is `if`` - all lower case - @Lemon.py 's comment had a minor error.